# Fix Flash memory leak during the runtime

Tags: flash, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

There is a Flash application that uses hundreds MB of my memory during the runtime. Is it possible somehow to purge this memory manually ?

For example inject some

```
System.gc()
```

into whole `libflashplayer.so` ?

Comment: If your apps memory use doesnt go down on its own (when memory should no longer be needed) it suggests flashplayer isnt garbage collecting at all - usual suspect is not removing event listeners but running your app thru a profiler will tell you more (eg adobe scout)

Comment: The point is that it is not my application and I have no access to the sources. I am just looking some way to make Flash library to purge its memory  in the system.

Comment: ok. theres not much you can do then - running System.gc() wont help - all it does is make garbage collection happen earlier. if your app isnt already gc'ing on its own, calling gc() wont have any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GC runs periodically on its own already, so if GC does not free memory for you, then YOU have done something wrong with your Flash application.

If an object does not get GC'd even if no longer needed, you should manually check the code so that object should release all the event listeners. Perhaps you forgot to remove a `TimerEvent.TIMER` listener, or any other listener somewhere else. Make sure that you properly dereference all objects if you plan to no longer use that instance. This includes removing the object you no longer need from display list of its parent which you still need (but does not include emptying the display list of that object, as if it'll become dereferenced, its display list will no longer count as a valid link for nested objects, so that they could too get collected), and removing all the listeners that don't have the `useWeakReference` flag set to true at the time of adding from this object and all its contents (the listener that's not weakly referenced counts as a valid link). Basically, you should always have full control over which listener is attached to which object, and when to add or remove listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Not outside of debug mode.  If you're having serious issues with garbage collection, look at the thread here and the articles that were linked in the thread:

[Why isn't the AS3 garbage collector picking this up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238300/why-isnt-the-as3-garbage-collector-picking-this-up)